# EA - generating DDL script

Tags: mysql, ddl, enterprise-architect

I am using trial version of Enterprise Architect and I just created my database schema from which I want to generate MySQL script. I looked at manual and it says that I have to select package and then click on tools and then od database engineering. But in tools, I have no database engineering option, so I am asking if I am doing it wrong or if there is another option how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in you trial, choose Corporate or anything above Corporate edition to try Database Engineering.
If you still don't find it,

Goto View-> Workspaces & Commands, In the Commands tab, choose Complete.
This should resolve, but in case it doesn't, right click on the package -> Code Engineering -> Generate DDL.

Please note, you might also have to set default database for tables prior to generating DDL (To set it at model level, so that all your tables are created in with that set, Settings -> Database Datatypes-> Select the product and check set as default)